# Receive POST request in PHP from OpenLayers JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, post, openlayers

I have problems in receiving POST request in PHP. I'm using JavaScript to send data to a PHP page with POST request. The JavaScript is from OpenLayers.js, and the part that sends the request looks like this:

```
var postrequest = OpenLayers.Request.POST({
        url: "http://localhost/index.php",
        data: "success",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
    });
```

In PHP, I'm using this code to see, what I'm getting:

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

This is what happens:

1. index.php receives POST request.
2. FireBug also informs that POST Parameters contain Success, the one that was sent.
3. print_r($_POST); in index.php just gives this: array() and doesn't change after the POST request from JavaScript.

So the data is sent and received, but my PHP code doesn't somehow understand it, or I'm not using the right PHP function.

Any suggestions, where to look, and what to try?

Comment: PHP requires that any entry in _POST/_GET have a valid key:value construction - you're passing a simple "success" string, which is confusing - is that a value? then what's the key? Is it a key? there's no value. You can try reading the raw input from `php://input` instead.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I totally missed key/value construction, now I changed it. But print_r($_POST) is still empty.

Comment: Are you doing `data: "success=true"`? I don't know how openlayers works, but it could send that as a raw string as well. Does `data: {success: true}` change anything?

Comment: I'm doing `data: OpenLayers.Util.getParameterString({status: "success"})`. With that I get key/value pair as the POST request (FireBug shows this as parameters: (status success)), but PHP can't read it.

Comment: did you manage to find a solution? having same problem here.

Answer (score 5):

I think the "data" property needs to be an object containing key/value pairs.

eg:

```
var postrequest = OpenLayers.Request.POST({
        url: "http://localhost/index.php",
        data: {
          userName: "myUsername",
          password: "myPassword"
        },
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
    });
```

If this works when you print_r($_POST) you should see
array("userName" => "myUsername", "password" => "myPassword")

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I changed the code to post a key/value pair. Now I get status as the key and value "success", but still print_r($_POST) shows the empty array.

Comment: what about `print_r($_REQUEST)`?

Comment: Actually I got it working. When I look at the PHP response in FireBug, it tells this: `Array([status] => success)`. I guess `print_r($_POST)` and `print_r($_REQUEST)` are not supposed to write text in PHP page?

Comment: Well it would write the response and send it to the calling requester, in this case your AJAX query, so the AJAX response contains the php output.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need include XMLHttpRequest.js library, you can download it from this link

https://github.com/ilinsky/xmlhttprequest